# Menu Hambúrguer Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-3, bootstrap, menu

Minha aplicação tem um dashboard com uma coluna lateral esquerda, que é onde fica o menu. Quando essa página é aberta em telas menores a coluna some(isso já acontece), só que eu preciso que no lugar dela o menu Hamburguer apareça para que o usuário possa ter acesso ao menu.

Meu código está assim:

```
<body>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar opficio dashMenuFont">
                        <div class="nav-img">
                            <img src="img/userDefaultImage.png">
                            <p class="opficio-bold userName"><?php echo strtoupper($_SESSION ['nickUser']) ?></p>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dash-menu">
                            <a  href="dashboard.php?p=home"><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home      "></span> Início</p></a>
                            <a  href="dashboard.php?p=search"><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar</p></a>
                            <a  href="dashboard.php?p=watched"><p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span> Assistido</p></a>
                            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Bate-papo</p>
                            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Configurações</p><hr>
                            <p></p>
                            <p></p><hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-logo-bot">
                            <img src="img/nav-logo.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                        <?php
                        $link = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p');
                        include $link . ".php";

                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
```

O resultado é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E Mobile fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei buscar essa solução porém nada funcionou.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/macsupport/pen/bKFzD)

Comment: Então, é bem parecido com um código que eu havia usado, mas não funciona... eu só consigo fazer o botão aparecer se for na div fixa no topo(o que não pode) e mesmo assim quando clico no botão nada acontece